# Override horizontal positioning with ggrepel

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I'm working on a chart similar to a slopegraph, where I'd like to put labels along one or both sides with ample blank space to fit them on both sides. In cases where labels are very long, I've wrapped them using `stringr::str_wrap` to place linebreaks. To keep labels from overlapping, I'm using `ggrepel::geom_text_repel` with `direction = "y"` so the x-positions are stable but the y-positions are repelled away from one another. I've also got `hjust = "outward"` to align the left-side text at its right end and vice versa.

However, it seems that the repel positioning places the label's bounding box with an `hjust = "outward"`, but the text *within* that label has `hjust = 0.5`, i.e. text is centered within its bounds. Until now, I'd never noticed this, but with wrapped labels, the second line is awkwardly centered, whereas I'd expect to see both lines left-aligned or right-aligned.

Here's an example built off the `mpg` dataset.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggrepel)

df <- structure(list(long_lbl = c("chevrolet, k1500 tahoe 4wd, auto(l4)", 
                                  "chevrolet, k1500 tahoe 4wd, auto(l4)", "subaru, forester awd, manual(m5)", 
                                  "subaru, forester awd, manual(m5)", "toyota, camry, manual(m5)", 
                                  "toyota, camry, manual(m5)", "toyota, toyota tacoma 4wd, manual(m5)", 
                                  "toyota, toyota tacoma 4wd, manual(m5)", "volkswagen, jetta, manual(m5)", 
                                  "volkswagen, jetta, manual(m5)"), year = c(1999L, 2008L, 1999L, 
                                                                             2008L, 1999L, 2008L, 1999L, 2008L, 1999L, 2008L), mean_cty = c(11, 
                                                                                                                                            14, 18, 20, 21, 21, 15, 17, 33, 21)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                            "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

df_wrap <- df %>%  
  mutate(wrap_lbl = stringr::str_wrap(long_lbl, width = 25))

ggplot(df_wrap, aes(x = year, y = mean_cty, group = long_lbl)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = wrap_lbl),
                  direction = "y", hjust = "outward", seed = 57, min.segment.length = 100) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expand_scale(add = 10))
```

[image]

The same thing happens with other values of `hjust`. Looking at the function's [source](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/blob/306c07447684eb6e5b14d79018b06cfeb325c1ae/R/geom-text-repel.R#L434), I see a line that points to this issue:

```r
hjust = x$data$hjust %||% 0.5,
```

where `%||%` assigns 0.5 if `x$data$hjust` is null. That's as far as I understand, but it seems that the `hjust` I've set isn't being carried over to this positioning and is instead coming up null.

Have I missed something? Can anyone see where I might override this without reimplementing the whole algorithm? Or is there a bug here that drops my `hjust`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR: probably a bug

Long answer:

I think it might be a bug in the code. I checked the gtable of the plot you made, wherein the `hjust` was specified numerically and correctly:

```
# Assume 'g' is the plot saved under the variable 'g'
gt <- ggplotGrob(g)
# Your number at the end of the geom may vary
textgrob <- gt$grobs[[6]]$children$geom_text_repel.textrepeltree.1578
head(textgrob$data$hjust)
```

```
[1] 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

Which got me thinking that (1) the plot can't be fixed by messing around in the gtable and (2) the drawtime code for the `textrepeltree` class of grobs may contain some errors. This makes sense, since the labels are repositioned when the plot device is resized. So when we look at the `makeContent.textrepeltree()` code in the link you provided, we can see that the `hjust` parameter is passed on to `makeTextRepelGrobs()`. Let's have a look at the relevant formals:

```
makeTextRepelGrobs <- function(
  ...other_arguments...,
  just = "center",
  ...other_arguments...,
  hjust = 0.5,
  vjust = 0.5
) { ...body...}
```

We can see that `hjust` is a valid argument, but there also exists a `just` argument, which is an argument that is not passed on from `makeContent.textrepeltree()`.

When we look at the function body there are these two lines:

```
  hj <- resolveHJust(just, NULL)
  vj <- resolveVJust(just, NULL)
```

Where `resolveH/VJust` are imported from the grid package. The `resolveHJust()` essentially checks whether the second argument is `NULL` and if that is true, default to the first argument, otherwise return the second argument. You can see that the `hjust` that was passed on to `makeTextRepelGrobs()` does not get passed to `resolveHJust()`, and this seems to be the point where your `hjust` parameter is dropped unexpectedly.

Further down the code is where the actual text grobs are made:

```
  t <- textGrob(
    ...other_arguments...
    just = c(hj, vj),
    ...other_arguments...
  )
```

I imagine that the fix would be relatively straightforward: you would just have to supply `hjust` as the second argument to `resolveHJust()`. However, since that `makeTextRepelGrobs()` is internal to ggrepel and does not get exported, you would have to copy a lot of extra code to get this to work. (Not sure if only copying the `makeTextRepelGrob()` would be sufficient, haven't tested this)

All of this leaves me to conclude that the `hjust` that you specified in `geom_text_repel()` gets lost at the last moment of drawtime by the `makeTextRepelGrobs()` internal function.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I was having trouble tracing through all of the code. I'll dig around a bit more, then probably go ahead and file a github issue.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE (12 December 2019):**

FYI, this is now addressed in the development version of `ggrepel`, and the fix also applies to `geom_label_repel`. See [issue #137](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/issues/137) on GitHub.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
devtools::install_github("slowkow/ggrepel")


df <- structure(list(long_lbl = c("chevrolet, k1500 tahoe 4wd, auto(l4)", 
                                  "chevrolet, k1500 tahoe 4wd, auto(l4)", "subaru, forester awd, manual(m5)", 
                                  "subaru, forester awd, manual(m5)", "toyota, camry, manual(m5)", 
                                  "toyota, camry, manual(m5)", "toyota, toyota tacoma 4wd, manual(m5)", 
                                  "toyota, toyota tacoma 4wd, manual(m5)", "volkswagen, jetta, manual(m5)", 
                                  "volkswagen, jetta, manual(m5)"), year = c(1999L, 2008L, 1999L, 
                                                                             2008L, 1999L, 2008L, 1999L, 2008L, 1999L, 2008L), mean_cty = c(11, 
                                                                                                                                            14, 18, 20, 21, 21, 15, 17, 33, 21)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                            "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

df_wrap <- df %>%  
  mutate(wrap_lbl = stringr::str_wrap(long_lbl, width = 25))

# With geom_text_repel
ggplot(df_wrap, aes(x = year, y = mean_cty, group = long_lbl)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = wrap_lbl),
                  hjust = "outward",
                  direction = "y",
                  seed = 57,
                  min.segment.length = 100) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(add = 10))

# With geom_label_repel
ggplot(df_wrap, aes(x = year, y = mean_cty, group = long_lbl)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = wrap_lbl),
                  hjust = "outward",
                  direction = "y",
                  seed = 57,
                  min.segment.length = 100) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(add = 10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the update! Hope you don't mind, I just edited to add the issue number for people's reference