# Geom label repel when label is too long to fit in the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

Does anyone know how to ensure that all the labels fit into the frame or expand the it beyond the chart without having the labels cut off?

Would also love to know how i can adjust the position of the label boxes and if there's any way to wrap text around the box so it's not occupying the entire row.

```
ggplot(convo4_merge, aes(x=call_record , y=sentiment_score, color = currently_speaking)) +
geom_line() +
ggtitle("Sentiment Analysis for Conversation 4") +
geom_label_repel(data=subset(convo4_merge, sentiment_score >0.85 | sentiment_score < -0.80), aes(label=split_transcript), box.padding =unit(0.5,"lines"), point.padding= unit(0.3, "lines"), segment.size=0.2, segment.color= 'grey50') + theme_classic( )
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg0OW.png)

Comment: Please provide example data, and code.

Comment: You could add newlines `"\n"` for every 4th word. Or use str_wrap. see related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56028991/680068

Comment: ggplot(convo4_merge, aes(x=call_record , y=sentiment_score, color = currently_speaking)) +
geom_line() +
ggtitle("Sentiment Analysis for Conversation 4") +
geom_label_repel(data=subset(convo4_merge, sentiment_score >0.85 | sentiment_score < -0.80), aes(label=split_transcript), box.padding =unit(0.5,"lines"), point.padding= unit(0.3, "lines"), segment.size=0.2, segment.color= 'grey50') + theme_classic( )

Comment: I have also added how my table / data set looks like. ^ is the code. :)

Comment: [Add your data and code as text, not images](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62685234/edit).

Comment: hey, i am still unable to figure out how to add the data in the text. :/